Is this novel fractal dimension related to the conventional ball counting dimension?
According to Wikipedia, the Minkowski ball counting fractal dimension of a bounded set $S$ is defined by
$$\dim_\text{b}(S) := \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \frac {\log N(S,\varepsilon)}{\log(\varepsilon_o/\varepsilon)},$$
where $ N(S,\varepsilon)$ is the minimal number of balls of diameter $\epsilon$ required to cover $S$.  Note that I have modified the wikipedia page by putting $S$ into the expression for $N$, and I have inserted a normalization factor $\varepsilon_o$  in the denominator for reasons that hopefully will be clear below. Some authors have extended this definition to an unbounded set $S$ by taking the supremum over bounded subsets:
$$\dim_b (S)=\sup_{E \subset S, \rm ~bounded} \dim_b E.$$
Another extension of ball counting to an unbounded set $S$ might be:
$$\dim_\text{B}(S) := \lim_{\varepsilon_o \to \infty} \frac {\log N(S \cap \beta(\varepsilon_o),\varepsilon)}{\log(\varepsilon_o/\varepsilon)},$$
where $\beta(\varepsilon_o)$ is the ball of radius $\varepsilon_o$ centered at the origin.  Notice that the above limit is taken with respect to large $\varepsilon_o$.  In effect, in this definition the size of the balls decreases relative to the increasing size of the normalization factor.  Can you find a relationship between these the two definitions of fractal dimension?

Do you mean to have a $\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}$ too, or are you claiming that your definition doesn't depend on $\varepsilon$? What dimension do you (want to) get for a set like ${(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:|y|<1}$?

Yes, the definition is independent of $\epsilon$.

In regard to the second part of your question, if I just follow through the consequences of the definition, then what I come up with is that the dimension of your object is 1.  Interesting.

Yeah, your definition measures the "large-scale structure that becomes visible as you zoom out", as opposed to the small-scale structure of the set. It assigns dimension 0 to every bounded set.

Yea. I think that for 2D Brownian motion constructed from random steps of distance 1 unit, this form of fractal dimension might work, where as the conventional definition would just have dimension 1.

How are you trying to approach the idea of Brownian motion on a "fractal set"?  There is already a lot of work out there in that direction---Kigami has a couple of papers discussing diffusion on certain fractals (those which appear as the attractors of profinite(?) iterated function systems), and Uta Frieberg has done a lot of work on resistance measures (which relate to diffusion) on fractal sets which occur as the limiting objects of certain graph constructions.  These ideas are kind of tangentially related to the idea of Brownian motion, by they are related.

More relevant might be Kumagai, who is very much interested in Brownian motion on fractals.  And there is a book from the 90s by Lindstrøm(?) (it is, if I recall correctly, in the AMS Memoirs series---it has two-tone cover that is dark at the top and white on the bottom) that is more specifically about Brownian motions on fractals.

@XanderHenderson.  I haven't studied diffusion on fractal sets.   What I am suggesting is that if you create a shape (or path or trajectory) with Brownian motion and unit steps, then such a shape/trajectory might be a fractal in the above definition.  By contrast, such a path would have dimension 1 in a conventional fractal definition.

I am not sure that I understand what you are describing.  A Brownian motion can be obtained as a limit of discrete (in time and space) random walks, but a a random walk with unit steps is not, in and of itself, a Brownian motion.  It is also not clear to me how you are planning on getting a random walk on a fractal, nor the limiting process by which you would obtain a Brownian motion.  Again, I would suggest that you read Kumagai.

But maybe the random walk with unit steps would approach Brownian motion as you zoom out.   The definition of fractal dimension that I propose looks at the object as you zoom out.

The process of "zooming out" is identical to the process of decreasing the size of the steps (in space and time).  That is precisely what is meant when I say that Brownian motion can be realized as a limit of discrete random walks---the limit is taken by "zooming out" (decreasing the size of the steps).  It is just a matter of perspective.

Then we agree that zooming out is just a different perspective.   By the way, you haven't said anything about my definition of a fractal dimension in the question.

As I said in my meta comment when you asked if you should post this:  you don't write definitions first.  You propose problems first, then you try to solve those problems.  If you notice that some particular idea shows up over and over again, you might look for a shorthand, at which point you introduce a new definition.  I don't understand what problem your definition is supposed to solve, hence I don't really have anything concrete to say about it.

I get your point.  I was hoping you would say, "this definition is fundamentally flawed", or "this definition is "obviously equivalent to earlier definitions and redundant".   But you're saying that you don't waste your time thinking about a new definitions until it is claimed that the definition solves a problem.  Fair enough.  It's like when the Supreme Court says that they won't take a case unless someone can show they have been directly harmed by a law.    Let me think about how I can explain the problem I'm trying to solve in a reasonable amount of space.

I strongly do not believe that there is any connection between the two notions of dimension, simply because the usual definition measures the "small-scale" behaviour of the set, while your definition measures a "large-scale" behaviour of the set. I think what you should do, in order to motivate your definition or find something interesting in it, is to simply compute it for some sets and report interesting properties. For example, what is it for $S = \mathbb R$ in dimension $1$? Or for any interval? Or for other interesting sets? I'd like to see how this works.

A good example to showcase the difference between the two definitions is the union of a ball about the origin in $\Bbb R^n$ with a line passing through the origin. In the first definition, as $\varepsilon$ gets smaller, the contribution of the line to $N(S,\varepsilon)$ grows slower than the contribution of the ball, so the dimension is $n$. With your definition, the contribution of the ball is fixed, while the contribution of the line is proportional to $\varepsilon_0$, so the dimension is $1$. By doing such combos of other sets, I think you can get any two dimensions you want.

https://tglad.blogspot.com/2017/08/reframing-geometry-to-include-negative.html describes a signed dimension that looks like it might apply in this case, e.g. in 2D, a grid of lines has signed dimension +1-2 = -1.

I think you've found something interesting whether it's "useful" or not. Here's a follow-up idea: real-world objects that look like fractals are not fractals by either of these definitions (since they're neither unbounded nor infinitely fine). Is there a notion of dimension that can measure "intermediate scale" structure? (Maybe instead of just taking limits with respect to $\varepsilon$ and $\varepsilon_0$, look at other properties of this two-parameter function.)

@Karl.   Hmmm.   My instant reaction is that there is no such intermediate scale fractal.  You need to be taking in a limit in one direction of the other; infinitely fine or infinitely large.  But maybe I'm being quick to stomp on your suggestion. Maybe you can think of an example of an intermediate scale fractal?

For example, take the millionth iteration of the Sierpinski triangle construction. There ought to be a way of detecting a dimension value close to $\frac{\log3}{\log2}$ for this set. I'm thinking something like "persistent dimension" analogous to persistent homology.

@Claude.  In regards to https://tglad.blogspot.com/2017/08/reframing-geometry-to-include-negative.html   As you suggest, there are similarities between my fractal dimension and the negative dimension in that blog.  However, he has a double limit, over both $\omega \to \infty$ and $\epsilon \to 0$.  My definition has only the omega difference.  I'm not sure exactly what the implications are of this difference, but it is a significant difference.

Let $c, d$ be any positive real numbers and $n$ be an integer greater than both. Let $C\subset \Bbb R^n$ be a bounded set with Minkowski dimension $c$, and choose a countable set $D \subset \Bbb R^n$ such that for all $k, |D\cap \beta(kd)| = \lfloor kd\rfloor$.
Since there can be at most a finite number of elements of $D$ in each shell of inner radius $(k-1)d$ and outer radius $kd$ for some $k$, they must be isolated from each other. So there is some minimum distance $> 0$ between any two of the elements. Thus for small enough $\varepsilon > 0, N(D\cap \beta(\varepsilon_0),\varepsilon) = |D\cap\beta(\varepsilon_0)|$, and we should have $\dim_B(D) = d$. On the other hand $\dim_B(C) = 0$ since $C$ is bounded, and thus we should have $\dim_B(C\cup D) = d$ as well.
Because all of the points of $D$ are isolated, $\dim_b(D) = 0$ and therefore $\dim_b(C\cup D) = c$.
So knowing $\dim_b(S)$ tells you nothing about $\dim_B(S)$ or vice versa. Any pairing of values for the two dimensions may occur.

I think in the first paragraph that you have an upper case C that should be lower case.

Thanks for the answer to the question.  It turns out the answer is pretty obvious, as you have shown.  The two fractal dimensions do not tell us anything about each other.  It might be that my original question was not formulated in the most intelligent way.  Maybe @Xander is correct, which is to say that the interesting question is whether this novel definition of fractal dimension can solve a problem that the conventional definition does not.  I'm thinking about this now.

@Chris - yes, that should have been a small $c$. There was also a more substantial error in the 2nd paragraph that resulted from me forgetting details of the argument as I was working out how to write it down. There can be more than one point of $D$ in each shell, but only finitely many. I don't have a particular use for your definition in mind, but it does measure something different, and does so in a non-trivial way. That alone is interesting. Much of mathematics was invented before anyone had any idea of a practical use for it.
